# Using temporal controller with various raster files

Tags: qgis, raster, temporal-controller

I have 12 TIFF files representing monthly average rainfall. I am trying to make a simple animation (GIF), showing the variations from month to month. I have found tutorials on how to use temporal controller with vector data, but not with raster.

I am struggling since I used to have time manager and this was quite easy, but now time manager is not being updated and it doesn't run on my current QGIS version.

Are there other methods to create different raster file animation or how should I use Temporal Controller for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the temporal controller for this:
a) Set the time range for each raster layer->Layer properties->temporal->fixed range -> set start and end time:

[image]

b) Start the temporal controller panel:
(1) set time range to full range
(2) choose the time increment (depending on your data and time ranges for the rasters
(3) press play
(4) export frames to images

[image]